# Poor performance of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, information-schema

I'm running version 5.5.11 of MySQL and the performance when querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage table is really bad.

I have a simple select request:

```
SELECT REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
       , TABLE_NAME AS TableName
       , COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName
       , CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AS Db 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage
```

It takes, 8 seconds in average to return 400 rows. Is this a know issue? If so, is there a way to improve performance (a patch maybe?).

Comment: The information_schema is a view of all tables reside inside all database.I would not be surprise if it went slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using the tip given there :
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/

I switched from seconds to a hundred millisecond for the same query. This setting, saved my day :

```
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
```

Answer (score 4):

I found an interesting article here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema-optimization.html

I added WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myTable' to my query and I got massive performance improvements, coming from 8 seconds to 0.2!

Comment: In our case, the SQL is as below. This looks across *all* table schemas. Works better in MySQL 8, but is slow on MySQL 5.6.40.
```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE referenced_table_schema='DB_NAME' 
AND referenced_table_name='TBL_NAME'
```